# JNI vs JNA, calling Java from Fortran95

Tags: java, java-native-interface, fortran, jna

I am trying to implement the following:
Compute something in Java and return value to Fortran.
I implemented it using JNI and the sequence is as follows:

```
Fortran 95 -> C -> Java (Computes something)

 Java (returns value to Fortran 95) -> C -> Fortran95
```

Can this be achieved using `JNA`? If so, what are the advantages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fortan's shared libraries are compatible with C, so JNA should be able to access any interfaces exported, including those that have callback inputs.

The advantages of JNA over JNI:

- **Speed of development**  You don't have to configure or compile any native code, which can significantly speed up your development/build cycle.
- **Clarity**  JNA's mappings look just like the functions you'd be calling in native code, but you get to use Java semantics instead of translating Java into C/JNI, and then C/JNI into appropriate wrappers around Fortran
- **Maturity of Code** JNA has already worked out the gotchas and details of managing the native interface, so you can focus on solving your real problems instead of doing plumbing.  However, if you *like* to do plumbing, JNI is always there.

Comment: The big disadvantage of JNA is speed.  It is a lot slower than JNI.  It was noticeable even on a 3GHz Xeon.